# What makes this question opinion based?

Tags: discussion

I came across this question on Computer Science Stack Exchange: [Why did finite-state controller with datapath win?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/141994/115941)

It's a historical question that was well received. In the same spirit, I asked this question on Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange: [What are the factors that led to the digital revolution?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/575496/238188)

The question is about why digital electronics surpassed analog in communications and processing. It's hard to see why this question is opinion based. In fact, it looks very similar to the one asked on Computer Science Stack Exchange, since it is about why one technology/methodology got preferred over the other. This Q&A was partially inspired by the documentary from IEEE Information Society titled [The bit player](https://thebitplayer.com/) that I watched.

So why was it closed, and what is opinion based about it? I'd like to gain a better understanding so I can avoid it in the future.

Comment: I think because those question invite a bunch of unobjective speculation, especially the digital revolution one. The one about finite state controllers could be rephrased to be "what advantages dose it have over alternative approaches" would likely be better received as it rules out the *really* speculative factors. Rephrasing the question to ask about the history of development is also more likely to be better received than just asking "why did things turn out like this?" which is different than "how did things turn out like this?"

Answer (score 1):

SE EE has a much tighter interpretation of what is opinion based than most other SE groups - in my opinion. (SE "Skeptics" are bizarre, many others try to find a middle path). SE EE also have a tighter interpretation than many re what questions are relevant, what constitutes a shopping question and a few others as well.

This seems to be based on the attitudes and perceptions of the users who actively participate in voting on questions. I'm an SE EE moderator and I feel that the various vote-to-close attitudes are tighter than I would like - but there is little I can do to change the attitudes of the list members who are active in this area. I try to assist people who seem to have a genuine question which has been given short shrift. Some are 'somewhat unhappy' with people doing this.

In this specific case it seems to me to be closer to opinion based than some questions - BUT still liable to be of interest and value. It is likely that a historian or a philosophy of science expert could give a very useful and detailed answer. I just looked at your link - your self answer is a good one and a number of people here could add to that . I consider it 'a shame' to close a question with the amount of useful content that has been put in so far - but, as above, a lot of the time the community decides.

Comment: It seems that the only thing opinion based about this question is the relative importance of well known factors